# how to save or update multiple entity objects at a time in hibernate...?

Tags: hibernate

Consider that there is no relationship between both the table Employee and Manager(both tables taken for just demo). Just i have to know how we can save or update multiple entity object simultaneously. I dont know whether my approach is wrong or right.

> Session session = getSession();
>   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); 
>   String hql = "from Employee e where e.id = :empId";
>   Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
>   query.setString("empId", 1);
>   Employee emp= (Employee)query.uniqueResult();
>   emp.setStatus("Inactive");
>   session.saveOrUpdate(emp);
>
> hql = "from Manager where m.id = :mgrId";
>   Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
>   query.setString("mgrId", 100);
>   Manager mgr= (Manager)query.uniqueResult();
>   mgr.setStatus("Active");
>   session.saveOrUpdate(mgr);
>   tx.commit();

Comment: What are you trying to do? Save `emp` and `mgr` in the same transaction?

Comment: @mabi He is not using same transaction but he is actually using same reference for all the newly created transactions. That is not an issue. Off-course he has to think of improving his programming standards as like everyone .

Comment: @BalajiReddy I was trying to ask what he *wanted* to do, since the question is about *simultaneously* updating objects (which isn't exactly possible, hence my confusion). As for assigning `tx` twice, I'm pretty pragmatic about this.

Comment: @Mabi yeah i want to update emp and mgr in the same transaction, but its not happening only first object is updated ie emp.

Comment: @BalajiReddy now i think it would be clear i have update emp and mgr object in same transaction. as you are saying this is not possible to update, then what is the alternate or correct way to do this.plz let me know

Comment: @Naveen Updated the post. Please check.

Comment: So to be clear: the code you posted runs as is, produces no exception but does not generate an `UPDATE` for `mgr`? Have you checked if `mgr.status` already *is* "Active"?